# How do I invoke a function with the new value set from setState in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

Below is my sample code, I want to set the newList first then called the registerNumberFetch function. registerNumberFetch is also a asynchronous function. How do I do that?

```
  const { registerList } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const [newList, setNewList] = useState(0);

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (registerList.length === 0) {
      setNewList(0)
    } else {
      setNewList(registerList[0]) // set the new list to equal to the first value of registerList 
      registerNumberFetch(newList) // then pass the newer newList value to this function registerNumberFetch 
    }
  }, [newList, registerList])
```

Answer (score 0):

`setNewList` function call is asynchronous. Therefore there is no guarantee that `registerNumberFetch` will be called right after that.

you should move the `newList` dependency to another `useEffect` and call `registerNumberFetch` within it.

Try below,

```
  const { registerList } = useSelector((state) => state.user);
  const [newList, setNewList] = useState(0);

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (registerList.length === 0) {
      setNewList(0)
    } else {
      setNewList(registerList[0]) 
    }
  }, [registerList])

  useEffect(()=>{
    if (registerList.length !== 0) {
     registerNumberFetch(newList) 
    }
  }, [newList])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd separate `useEffect` in 2 parts. The first one is subscribed to `registerList`, second - to `newList`.

```
// first 
useEffect(() => {
    if (registerList.length === 0) {
      setNewList(0)
    } else {
      setNewList(registerList[0])
    }
},
[registerList]);

//second
useEffect(() => {
    registerNumberFetch(newList)
}, [newList])
```